# how to assert date time stamp is within 2 minutes?

Tags: java, assert, assertion

I want to have assertion to make sure the data retrieved is within

1. print data1
   2020-03-16 09:08:49
2. print data2
   2020-03-16 09:09:15
3. assertThat time gap between data1 and data2 is not more than 2 minute then Passed.

I have sample codes, is this the best way?
any suggestion, please comment.

```
 //data1 
 Date data1 = new Date();
 //data2 
 Date data2 = new Date();
 //assert
 assertThat(data1, DateMatchers.within(2, ChronoUnit.MINUTES, data2 ));
```

latest script

```html
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*

import java.sql.*
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI

import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable
import java.text.ParseException
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import com.kms.katalon.core.configuration.RunConfiguration

GlobalVariable.TestIssueKey = null


WebUI.delay(1)


//SQL statement
dbQuery2 = /SELECT * FROM drugs.sync/


//Connect to PostgresSQL, global variable is stored at profile
List results = CustomKeywords.'test.database.getPostgresSQLResults'(GlobalVariable.dbConnString2 , GlobalVariable.dbUsername2 , GlobalVariable.dbPassword2 ,GlobalVariable.dbDriver2 ,dbQuery2 )

//SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
String date = sdf.format(new Date())

//print the "lastupdatedwm6" column for PULL
String lastupdatedwm6 = results.get(0).get('lastupdatedwm6')

//store the lastupdatedwm6 to file
def lastupdatedwm6aft = new File(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/lastupdatedwm6aft.txt")
lastupdatedwm6aft.newWriter().withWriter { it << lastupdatedwm6 }
println lastupdatedwm6aft.text


WebUI.delay(2)
//Read data before drugsync Pull
def lastupdatedwm6bef = new File(RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + "/Data Files/lastupdatedwm6bef.txt")


 Date data1 = sdf.parse(lastupdatedwm6bef.text);
 Date data2 = sdf.parse(lastupdatedwm6aft.text);

 long diffInMillies = Math.abs(data2.getTime() - data1.getTime());
 long minute_millis_2 = 2 * 60 * 1000;
 long diffTime = minute_millis_2 - diffInMillies;
 assertTrue(diffTime > 0);
```

Comment: what do you mean with best?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test
public void test() throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);

    Date data1 = sdf.parse("2020-03-16 09:08:49");
    Date data2 = sdf.parse("2020-03-16 09:09:49");

    long diffInMillies = Math.abs(data2.getTime() - data1.getTime());
    long minute_millis_2 = 2 * 60 * 1000;
    long diffTime = minute_millis_2 - diffInMillies;
    assertTrue(diffTime > 0);
}
```

Comment: i have used your approach but hitting error groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1584408493586.assertTrue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [true]

Comment: @user12158726 probably you have a different library at your code for Junits. Use the fuction available at your end, which checks diffTime should be greater than 0

Comment: @user12158726 I am using this---> import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use timeout.

```
// This will fail if the test takes more than 1000 milliseconds
@Test(timeout=1000)
public void test() {
  objectToTest.methodThatTakesALongTime();
}
```